# Initialize the chart from widget on IONIC 3

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, tradingview-api

I want to use trading-view widget for my application, and the widget from trading-view is

```
<!-- TradingView Widget BEGIN -->
<div class="tradingview-widget-container">
  <div class="tradingview-widget-container__widget"></div>
  <div class="tradingview-widget-copyright"><a href="https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/OANDA-USDCAD/technicals/" rel="noopener" target="_blank"><span class="blue-text">Technical Analysis for USDCAD</span></a> by TradingView</div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-technical-analysis.js" async>
  {
  "width": "500",
  "height": "450",
  "locale": "en",
  "symbol": "OANDA:USDCAD",
  "interval": "1D"
}
  </script>
</div>
<!-- TradingView Widget END -->
```

I added the script from tradingview on my html.index after polyfills

```
<!-- The polyfills js is generated during the build process -->
  <script src="build/polyfills.js"></script>

 <!-- TradingView Script-->
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/external-embedding/embed-widget-technical-analysis.js" async></script>
```

on the home.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
declare var embed-widget-technical-analysis: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController){}

ionViewDidLoad(){

     new embed-widget-technical-analysis.widget({
   "container_id": "myContainer",
   "width": "500",
  "height": "450",
  "locale": "en",
  "symbol": "OANDA:USDCAD",
  "interval": "1D"
})

}


}
```

On home.html

```
<ion-content padding>
        <div id="myContainer">
            </div>
</ion-content>
```

On home.ts it is showing me error " can not find name embed-widget-technical-analysis, what i'm did wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

Change the '-' to '_' on variable.
embed-widget-technical-analysis ->     embed_widget_technical_analysis
Should work